# Sort lines based on a variable-width number at a fixed position

Tags: sort

I'm trying to sort a file using the Sort command but its not working:

The file contains lines like:

```
photo1
photo11
photo12
photo13
photo17
photo18
photo19
photo2
photo22
photo23
photo25
photo26
photo27
```

I'm using the command, `sort -k6 Photos` so that it start sorting after the string "photo", can someone tell where I'm going wrong??

Comment: 1. You need to use `-n` or `-g` to sort numerically. 2. `-k5` says to use the fifth whitespace-separated field as a key. I'm not sure `sort` can even handle starting in the middle of a field

Comment: Ahh its 6 then, but it doesn't work as well

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It does work, only not as you expect. What is the output, and what do you expect?

Answer (score 5):

Define the sort key with the start and stop character position of the key:

```
sort -nk1.6,1.8 file
```

See your friendly `sort` manpages.

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution.

Comment: what to do if the start of the number is not known, e.g. I want `photo1 < photo2 < phot3 < photooo4 < photo5`

Comment: If the number doesn't begin at a fixed offset, inject a unique delimiter where the number begins to create a new field. Then sort using the delimiter and finally remove it: `sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/:\1/' file | sort -t: -nk2,2 | tr -d ":"`

Comment: You can also add --debug to see if you're sorting by the right set of characters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a field separator.

```
sort -n -to -k3 Photos
```

`-to` tells `sort` to use `o` as the field separator. The numbers are in the third field (the first field contains `ph` and the second field contains `t`) so we use `-k3`. `-n` tells `sort` to sort numerically instead of alphabetically.